# How to use when condition in ansible yaml file?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I want something like:

if env == 'dev'

```
  - hosts: "{{host}}"
    user: root
```

else if env == 'prod'

```
 - hosts: "{{host}}"
   user: centos
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible uses the Jinja2 templating engine, which lets you do:

```
{% if env == 'dev' %}
- hosts: "{{host}}"
  user: root
{% elif env == 'prod' %}
- hosts: "{{host}}"
  user: centos
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer not to put these kind of decisions into the template itself, I would use something like this in the config:

```
user_by_env:
  dev: root
  prod: centos

user: "{{ user_by_env[env] }}"
```

Then in the template:

```
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  user: "{{ user }}"
```

This also loudly fails in case the env is not dev/prod instead of silently producing an incorrect file.